# Node.js: promisifying callback library for 'yield' keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, bluebird

I'm trying to build a simple REST API with Koa.js. It uses ES6 generator functions, which I find much more pleasant than callbacks (they're just like C#'s async-await). The yield keyword expects a thenable (promise, thunk, generator). I'm using Bluebird's promisifyAll method to promisify callback libraries (request in my case), but I still keep getting error. Here are my code and the error:

```
var koa = require('koa')
, route = require('koa-route')
, app = module.exports = koa()
, Promise = require('bluebird')
, request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));

app.use(route.get('/users', list));

function *list() {
  var res = yield request.get('http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users');
  this.body = res.body;
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Stack trace for the error:

```
Error: yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object
    at next (/Users/jashua/Desktop/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:109:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jashua/Desktop/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:50:5)
    at next (/Users/jashua/Desktop/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:93:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jashua/Desktop/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:50:5)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/jashua/Desktop/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:121:8)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:504:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:357:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:104:17)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluebird adds an `Async` suffix to promisified functions with promisifyAll.

Try:

```
  var res = yield request.getAsync('http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users');
```

Comment: Also note, you can use `Promise.coroutine` which comes with Bluebird to run generators.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you foresee any issues if I have a bunch of libraries I need to run through this process (oauth2, redis, elasticsearch etc)? Any other issues with the framework? I'm surprised Koa hasn't become very popular, especially considering how much more readable the code is compared to callbacks.